# In calendar, how to change the background color of selected item in android grid view

Tags: android-calendar

[image]

[image]

In calendar, When i select the date, I need to change the background color of grid item and also remove the background of previous selected item. When i click and hold the date 10, (Shown in image 2), its showing a orange color. But when i unfocused the mouse, its not showing the Color.

gridcell.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {


                            String date_month_year = (String) v.getTag();
                            selected_date = date_month_year;
                            String[] day_color = date_month_year.split("-");
                            String theday = day_color[0];
                            selectedDateEvents(theday);
                            listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            prev_pos = cur_pos;
                            cur_pos = position;

                            Log.d("curr and prev", position+"  n  "+prev_pos);

                            parent.getChildAt(cur_pos).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_tile_small);
                            parent.getChildAt(prev_pos).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_tile_small_black);

                            GridCellAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    });
```

Please can someone help me?